# Hover functionality for Checkbox and Radiobutton with data-ui tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

i have a very simple task:

- create the function which finds checkboxes or radiobuttons with data-ui tag
- bind to the label of the checkbox or radiobutton with mouseover and mouse out events
- add class on label hover and remove class by label hover out

and here is my code

```js
var HoverRadioCheck = {

  init: function() {
    this.findRadioCheckInput();
    this.bindToLabel();
  },

  findRadioCheckInput: function() {
      $("input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox']").find.dataAttr('ui-checkbox', 'ui-radiobutton');

  },

  bindToLabel: function() {
      $("input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox'] + label").bind( "mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "entered" );
      });

    }

};

HoverRadioCheck.init();
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <input name="checkbox_test_2" id="checkbox_test_2_1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-ui-checkbox/>
        <label for="checkbox_test_2_1">Bacon ipsum dolor amet salami andouille corned beef</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input name="radiobutton_test_1" id="radiobutton_test_1_1" class="radiobutton" type="radio" data-ui-radiobutton/>
    <label for="radiobutton_test_1_1">Lorem Ipsum</label>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: care to mention what is the actual problem you are facing & what you are looking for ?

Comment: Sorry for such a vague question/code. My question is: how should i implement those 3 tasks? What is correct way to write function which finds checkboxes or radiobuttons with data-ui tag? checkbox/radiobutton should be bound together with the label, which we can see it with mouseover/out.

Comment: Check if my answer is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now its clear, What you did is good but there are few changes, let me explain:

1) There is no JQuery function named `item.find.dataAttr` or even `item.dataAttr`, it should be either `item.data('ui-checkbox')` or `item.attr('data-ui-checkbox')`

**Invalid:**

`$("input[type='radio']").find.dataAttr('ui-radiobutton');`

`$("input[type='radio']").dataAttr('ui-radiobutton');`

**Valid:**

`$("input[type='radio']").attr('data-ui-radiobutton');`

`$("input[type='radio']").data('ui-radiobutton');`

Basically `attr()` function looks for ANY attribute in an element so you HAVE to give the entire name of the attribute but `data()` function on the other hand looks for only a `data-` attribute so in that case you need to give just the name after the `data-`, say `ui-radiobutton`. `find()` on the other hand is entirely different - It finds an ELEMENT rather than an attribute, so basically for your requirement you don't even need it. An example to use `find()` could be:

`$('.form-group').find('input[type='radio']'); //this will give you the radio ELEMENTs`

2) This is rather simple, your `bindToLabel` function is fine except you need to provide the `+ label` even to the first parameter. Yours is not invalid but it won't bind the radio button's label but will bind the radio button itself. I assume you don't want that. So it should be:

`$("input[type='radio'] + label, input[type='checkbox'] + label").bind(`

So your final JQuery should look like - [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/jrRbAO)

```
var HoverRadioCheck = {

  init: function() {
    this.findRadioCheckInput();
    this.bindToLabel();
  },

  findRadioCheckInput: function() {
      $("input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox']").data('ui-checkbox', 'ui-radiobutton');
  },

  bindToLabel: function() {
      $("input[type='radio'] + label, input[type='checkbox'] + label").bind( "mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "entered" );
      });
    }

};

HoverRadioCheck.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused about What do you really need... But I tried to make your code works ... but for sure this is not the best way!

```js
var HoverRadioCheck = {

  init: function() {
    this.findRadioCheckInput();
    this.bindToLabel();
  },

  findRadioCheckInput: function() {
      var elements=$("input[type='radio'][data-ui-radiobutton], input[type='checkbox'][data-ui-checkbox]").find("input");
      elements.prevObject.each(function(){
          var id=$(this).attr("id");
          if($("label[for="+id+"]").length>0)
          {
            $("label[for="+id+"]").bind( "mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("entered");
            });
          }
      });  
  },

  bindToLabel: function() {
      
    }

};

HoverRadioCheck.init();
```

```css
.entered
{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
        <input name="checkbox_test_2" id="checkbox_test_2_1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-ui-checkbox/>
        <label for="checkbox_test_2_1">Bacon ipsum dolor amet salami andouille corned beef</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input name="radiobutton_test_1" id="radiobutton_test_1_1" class="radiobutton" type="radio" data-ui-radiobutton />
    <label for="radiobutton_test_1_1">Lorem Ipsum</label>
</div>
```

I've added a small css class "entered" .. to be able to check when mouse enter / leave

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and trying to make sense of my code, i apologize for this chaos. Question: how would code those 3 tasks I've written? ignoring my jquery code completely.

Comment: You're welcome, Glad to help you. Code didn't ignore your jQuery code but the selectors/methods you used were not totally right ... for example dataAttr is not a jQuery method, if you need to select an element using jQuery, you can check this URL https://api.jquery.com/?s=selectors

Comment: Also please if my answer helped you, please accept it (Click on the check mark next to my answer) .. Thank you! @Arual